# Carbon date comparison wrong by 1 hour

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

So, this doesn't seem right to me. When comparing two dates with the same timezone with just a one minute difference, it's telling me there is a 59 minute difference.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');   

$stored_time = "2020-03-10 07:37:37 PM EST"; //Aprox 1 minute before Carbon::now()
$stored_time = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:i:s A T', $stored_time, 'EST');
echo $stored_time . "\n";
echo Carbon::now() . "\n";
$minutes_difference = Carbon::now()->diffInMinutes($stored_time);

echo $minutes_difference;
```

I'm currently using the workaround below, but this doesn't make much sense to me. Additionally, when I echo out both `$stored_time` and `Carbon::now()` it's not *showing* an hours difference unless using `diffInMinutes()` method

```
$stored_time = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:i:s A T', $stored_time, 'EST')->subHour(1);
```

Edit: Adjusting stored_time to "2020-03-10 09:27:37 PM EST" (about 3 minutes before I ran the script) this is the output:

```
stored_time: 2020-03-10 21:27:37
Carbon::now():2020-03-10 21:30:00
time(): 1583890200
minutes_difference: 57
```

Comment: Could you provide the exact output of the script above, plus add the `echo time(), "\n";` as another line

Comment: Edited in the output into the question, thanks!

Comment: Do you also realise that at the moment it's `EDT` observed in the `America/New_York`, and not `EST`? It's one of the reasons short timezone names are confusing and ambiguous.

Comment: Was vaguely aware of that but didn't think it mattered since EDT and EST are both returning the same time. I just want to keep everything east coast time to keep things simple for myself. I've tried using EDT in createFromFormat() method and format() method for Carbon::now() and got the same results

Comment: "EDT and EST are both returning the same time" --- they cannot, those are 2 different timezones which stand 1hr apart. https://3v4l.org/bpg9j

Comment: Interesting, I was not aware. When typing in "EDT time" and "EST time" into google it returns the same time. I tried setting date_default_timezone_set to 'US/Eastern' as well as Carbon::now('US/Eastern') but it's still returning an hour difference. Any thoughts?

Comment: Your posted code is broken because you're using `EST` while it's `EDT` now. I cannot tell anything about `US/Eastern` since you haven't provided the complete example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the same `America/New_York` timezone consistently through your code, you'll get the expected results.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$stored_time = "2020-03-11 12:25:00 AM America/New_York";
$stored_time = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:i:s A T', $stored_time, 'America/New_York');
echo $stored_time . "\n";
echo Carbon\Carbon::now() . "\n";
$minutes_difference = Carbon\Carbon::now()->diffInMinutes($stored_time);
echo $minutes_difference;
```

Output:

```
2020-03-11 00:25:37
2020-03-11 00:24:58
0
```

Using human-readable time zones can cause problems; it's best to stick to what computers recognize best.